# how do I test node.js template render in jest

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

This is one of my routes.

```
const actor = await Actor.findById(req.params.id);
if(!actor) throw new Error("Actor not found");
res.render('admin/actors/edit_actor',{actor:actor});
```

The thing is I don't know how to test if valid actor gets returned because of render function.

================================================================

If I write the following

```
const actor = await Actor.findById(req.params.id);
    if(!actor) throw new Error("Actor not found");
    res.send({actor:actor});
```

I know how to test this because this actor would be in body parameters. such as:

//test

```
const res = await request(server).get('/actor/2');
```

res.body is the same as actor

So questions:

1) how do I test the first example which renders some view?

2) first example to test there's an integration test needed. and for the second example, we should write functional test. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

In an unit test you're supposed to mock your dependencies, so if you're testing your controller you should mock the `req` and `res` objects as well as the model. For example

## Implementation

```
import Actor from '../model/Actor';

const controller = (req, res) => {
  const actor = await Actor.findById(req.params.id);
  if(!actor) throw new Error("Actor not found");
  res.render('admin/actors/edit_actor',{actor:actor});
}
```

## Unit Test

```
import Actor from '../model/Actor';

jest.mock('../model/Actor');

describe('controller', () => {
  const req = {
    params: { id: 101 }
  };

  const res. = {
    render: jest.fn()
  };

  beforeAll(() => {
    Actor.findById.mockClear();
    controller(req, res);
  });

  describe('returning an actor', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      res.render.mockClear();
      Actor.findById.mockResolvedValue({
        name: "Some Actor"
      });
      controller(req, res);
    });

    it('should get actor by id', () => {
      expect(Actor.findById).toHaveBeenCalledWith(101);
    });

    it('should call res.render', () => {
      expect(res.render).toHaveBeenCalledWith('admin/actors/edit_actor', { actor });
    })
  });

  describe('not returning an actor', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      res.render.mockClear();
      Actor.findById.mockResolvedValue(undefined);
      controller(req, res);
    });
    it('should throw an Error', () => {
      expect(() => controller(req, res)).toThrow(Error);
    });

    it('should not call res.render', () => {
      expect(res.render).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```